# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xlabel'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I read all the similar questions about this error, they are either spelling mistakes or importing the `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` wrong.

My code is as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline

plt.hist(raw_data['smoker'], bins=3, color='gray')
plt.xlabel('Smoker')
plt.show()
```

I'm not sure what is the reason for this error. Might be library version? I didn't find anything about that

This is the error:
`AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'xlabel'`

Answer (score 0):

I am using `matplotlib` version `3.5.2` and it works

You can try with this command:

```
pip install matplotlib==3.5.2
```